# Change Wordpress Loop Order from 'desc' to 'asc' with click or dropdown

Tags: php, loops, wordpress

I'm a PHP newbie and I need to do the following:

• Create a dropdown menu or link that changes a WordPress loop from 'desc' to 'asc' when selected or clicked.

Here's the my loop code:

```
<?php
    global $wp_query; $post; $post_id = $post-> ID;
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    rewind_posts();
    $temp = $wp_query;
    $wp_query = NULL;

    $post_type = 'post'; // change this to the post type you want to show
    $show_posts = '20'; // change this to how many posts you want to show
    $category_name = 'used-cars'; // change this to the category name you need
    $order_by = 'meta_value_num';
    $meta_key = 'price';
    $order = 'desc' 

  ?>


  <?php $wp_query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=' . $category_name . '&post_type=' . $post_type . '&posts_per_page=' . $show_posts . '&paged=' . $paged . '&orderby=' . $order_by . '&meta_key=' . $meta_key . '&order=' . $order ); ?>

      <?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

      <div style="width: 670px; height: 170px; border-bottom: 3px solid #ccc; width: 100%; padding-top: 20px;">

        <!-- POST THUMB -->

        <div style="float: left; width: 150px;">

          <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>

            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' ); ?></a>

          <?php else : ?>

            <div style="width: 150px; height: 150px; border: 1px solid #efefef;">

              <p style="text-align: center; margin-top: 60px;">No Pictures Available</p>

            </div>

          <?php endif; ?>

        </div>

        <!-- POST CONTENT RIGHT -->

        <div style="float: left; margin: 0px 0 0 20px; width: 450px;">

            <div style="float: left; width: 245px; height: 150px;">

            <!-- POST INNER LEFT -->

            <h2 style="margin-bottom: 20px; font-size: 16px;"><a class="loop-link" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></h2>

              <div style="float: left; width: 70px; height: 120px;">
                <p style="font-size: 12px;"><strong>Year/Reg:</strong></p>
                <p style="font-size: 12px;"><strong>Fuel Type:</strong></p>
                <p style="font-size: 12px;"><strong>Colour:</strong></p>
                <p style="font-size: 12px;"><strong>Mileage:</strong></p>
                <p style="font-size: 12px;"><strong>Gearbox:</strong></p>
              </div>

              <div style="float: left; width: 70px; height: 120px; text-align:right;">
                <p style="font-size: 12px;"><?php the_field('year-reg'); ?></p>
                <p style="font-size: 12px;"><?php the_field('fuel_type'); ?></p>
                <p style="font-size: 12px;"><?php the_field('colour'); ?></p>
                <p style="font-size: 12px;"><?php the_field('mileage'); ?></p>
                <p style="font-size: 12px;"><?php the_field('gearbox'); ?></p>
              </div>

            </div>

            <!-- POST INNER RIGHT -->

            <div style="float: right; margin: 0; width: 170px; height: 150px; border-left: 1px solid #efefef; text-align: right;">

                <h2>Price: <?php the_field('price'); ?></h2>

                <br>


                <a class="view-button" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">VIEW THIS USED CAR</a>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>

                <!-- SHARE BUTTONS -->

                    <p>SHARE THIS CAR</p>
                    <span class='st_facebook'></span>
                    <span class='st_twitter'></span>
                    <span class='st_googleplus'></span>
                    <span class='st_linkedin'></span>
                    <span class='st_pinterest'></span>
                    <span class='st_email'></span>

            </div>

        </div>



      </div>

      <?php endwhile; ?>

  <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

The code is for a car website and you can view the page here:

http://temp51.clrs-hosting.co.uk/used-cars

I've search for days to find a solution to this, however, I've not been able to find any. Again, as I said, I'm new to PHP, so any help or advice would be great. Any ideas, internet friends?

Slainté.

Comment: Have you made any attempts to (a) create a dropdown menu and/or sort link, (b) work out how to change the sort order, or (c) find out how forms work so you can implement the change in sort order?

Comment: Hi there, I've searched online through wordpress support forums etc. I can create the form, no problem. I just need to find out how the correct code to include in the <li>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following code and now call the file using
filename.php?order=desc
or
filename.php?=order=asc

it will change accordingy

```
            <?php
                global $wp_query; $post; $post_id = $post-> ID;
                $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
                rewind_posts();
                $temp = $wp_query;
                $wp_query = NULL;

                $post_type = 'post'; // change this to the post type you want to show
                $show_posts = '20'; // change this to how many posts you want to show
                $category_name = 'used-cars'; // change this to the category name you need
                $order_by = 'meta_value_num';
                $meta_key = 'price';
                $order = ($_GET["order"]);; 

              ?>


              <?php $wp_query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=' . $category_name . '&post_type=' . $post_type . '&posts_per_page=' . $show_posts . '&paged=' . $paged . '&orderby=' . $order_by . '&meta_key=' . $meta_key . '&order=' . $order ); ?>

                  <?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

                  <div style="width: 670px; height: 170px; border-bottom: 3px solid #ccc; width: 100%; padding-top: 20px;">

                    <!-- POST THUMB -->

                    <div style="float: left; width: 150px;">

                      <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>

                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' ); ?></a>

                      <?php else : ?>

                        <div style="width: 150px; height: 150px; border: 1px solid #efefef;">

                          <p style="text-align: center; margin-top: 60px;">No Pictures Available</p>

                        </div>

                      <?php endif; ?>

                    </div>

                    <!-- POST CONTENT RIGHT -->

                    <div style="float: left; margin: 0px 0 0 20px; width: 450px;">

                        <div style="float: left; width: 245px; height: 150px;">

                        <!-- POST INNER LEFT -->

                        <h2 style="margin-bottom: 20px; font-size: 16px;"><a class="loop-link" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></h2>

                          <div style="float: left; width: 70px; height: 120px;">
                            <p style="font-size: 12px;"><strong>Year/Reg:</strong></p>
                            <p style="font-size: 12px;"><strong>Fuel Type:</strong></p>
                            <p style="font-size: 12px;"><strong>Colour:</strong></p>
                            <p style="font-size: 12px;"><strong>Mileage:</strong></p>
                            <p style="font-size: 12px;"><strong>Gearbox:</strong></p>
                          </div>

                          <div style="float: left; width: 70px; height: 120px; text-align:right;">
                            <p style="font-size: 12px;"><?php the_field('year-reg'); ?></p>
                            <p style="font-size: 12px;"><?php the_field('fuel_type'); ?></p>
                            <p style="font-size: 12px;"><?php the_field('colour'); ?></p>
                            <p style="font-size: 12px;"><?php the_field('mileage'); ?></p>
                            <p style="font-size: 12px;"><?php the_field('gearbox'); ?></p>
                          </div>

                        </div>

                        <!-- POST INNER RIGHT -->

                        <div style="float: right; margin: 0; width: 170px; height: 150px; border-left: 1px solid #efefef; text-align: right;">

                            <h2>Price: <?php the_field('price'); ?></h2>

                            <br>


                            <a class="view-button" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">VIEW THIS USED CAR</a>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <br>

                            <!-- SHARE BUTTONS -->

                                <p>SHARE THIS CAR</p>
                                <span class='st_facebook'></span>
                                <span class='st_twitter'></span>
                                <span class='st_googleplus'></span>
                                <span class='st_linkedin'></span>
                                <span class='st_pinterest'></span>
                                <span class='st_email'></span>

                        </div>

                    </div>



                  </div>

                  <?php endwhile; ?>

              <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Worked like a treat, Pavan. Thank you very much.

Comment: no prob :) Happy to help :) let me know if you require any other modifications